# RDLC tablix show dynamic results in multiple columns

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have rdlc report tablix show result set. The rdlc design is as  follows
[image: Grid Dsign]

It shows the result as follows
[image: Result Display]

If I got 12 records in the result is there any option to show the result in two columns 
[image: Expected output]